# Orientation type of the sensor

Tags: android, orientation, accelerometer, sensors, gyroscope

What data are used by orientation sensor in the android Samsung Galaxy S 2. Gyroscope's data or accelerometer's data?

Comment: Questions should relate to programming, not device specification

Answer (score 2):

I have recently answered a similar question (you can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092346/gyroscope-included-in-getorientation/8389912#8389912)). The brief answer is this:

*"The methods included in the Android APIs to get the orientation does not include readings from the gyroscope sensor. Gyroscope does not provide information about orientation, since it only has information about rotation speed"*.

Answer (score 1):

Samsung Galaxy S2 has a [boatload of sensors](http://androidfragmentation.com/database/v/dr/491886/oem/samsung/dm/GT-I9100/carrier/O2%20-%20UK), a magnetic/orientation one from Asahi Kasei Microdevices and also a gyroscope one from STMicroelectronics. Could you use Market apps AndroSensor and Sensor List to verify and let us know?